# Recursive JavaScript function continues to run after returning

Tags: javascript, recursion, frontend, callstack, web-frontend

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that recursively searches for a file/directory in a file structure and returns that file if found. This is an example of the file structure:

```
var fileStructure = [
  {'pictures': ['picture1.png', {'beach': ['picture2.png']}]},
  {'videos': ['video1.mov', 'video2.mov']}
]
```

In the dictionaries, the key represents the name of a directory and the value represents the contents of the directory. Each item in the arrays are files. So, if I called `findFile('picture1.png')` I should get true, or if I call `findFile('videos')` I should also get true. Here is what I have so far:

```js
var fileStructure = [{ "music": [{ "acoustic": ["vlad-gluschenko-stars-extended.mp3"] }, { "chinese": ["AlbumArtSmall.jpg", "Folder.jpg", "keys-of-moon-yugen.mp3"] }, { "lofi": ["le-gang-relax-man.mp3", "purple-cat-field-of-fireflies.mp3"] }] }, { "sounds": [{ "campfire": ["fire-crackle.mp3", "fire-rumble.mp3"] }, { "rain": ["rain-heavy.mp3", "rain-light.mp3", "rain-tapping.mp3"] }, { "thunderstorm": ["thunderstorm.mp3"] }, { "wind": ["wind-base.mp3", "wind-howling.mp3", "wind-rattling.mp3"] }] }]

function findFile(fileName, dir) {
    for (i in dir) {
        let entry = dir[i];

        // If entry is a dictionary, unpack into array
        if (entry.constructor == Object) {
            // If the file being searched for is itself a directory
            if (Object.keys(entry).indexOf(fileName) != -1) {
                // !!!!! THIS PRINTS BUT THE FUNCTION KEEPS RUNNING !!!!!
                console.log(`Found directory: ${fileName}`);
                return true;
            }
            entry = Object.values(entry);
        }

        // If entry is an array (meaning it is the contents of a directory)
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            findFile(fileName, entry);
        }
        // Found file
        else if (entry == fileName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// 
fileExists = findFile('tets', fileStructure);
console.log("done", fileExists);

fileExists = findFile('lofi', fileStructure);
console.log("done", fileExists);
```

In my code I called this function like so: `fileExists = findFile('lofi', audioLibrary);` If you look at my comment surrounded by exclamation points, that line prints as expected, however even after returning true the function continues to run and, ultimately, the fileExists variables evaluates to false.

**Why does the loop seem to continue even after returning?**

[This](https://i.gyazo.com/db035cf763d53c08c9c6bba0dbea2c6a.mp4) is what happened when I added a breakpoint to the return line. As you can see the loop runs again.

**EDIT:**
Added the file structure that I am using.

Comment: your code works fine. run the code snippet in your question. chances are you have the same function running in multiple places, but as it is here, it works fine.

Comment: You’re not doing anything with the recursive return value of `findFile`. The `return` only ends the current call, not the entire call stack.

Comment: Pretend the recursive call to `findFile` would call *any* other function, its return shouldn’t end *your* function, right? Same thing here.

Comment: you probably want to `return findFile(fileName, entry);`

Comment: I am not sure why my function would be running in multiple places aside from when it calls itself. In my case, I receive the output: "Found directory: lofi", and at that point, I would assume that fileExists would be true. However, the function continues (probably called in anothe rplace somehow) and fileExists is false.

Comment: And why would I want to return findFile(fileName, entry)? Wouldn't that keep the function from searching the rest of the items in the directory?

Comment: the function will run before it returns, it just ensures that the outer function retunrs whatever the recursed function returns.

Comment: Right, I am understanding now also with the help of some people on discord. This will just take some refactoring, so I will close the post. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I wasn't actually returning `findFile(fileName, entry);`, so the function would only search one directory, and there was no actual recursion (duh lol!) To solve this I kept track of all the sub-directories within the current directory being searched with a variable of `directories`. Then, once the last file in the directory being searched was checked, if no results were found, it would try searching each directory in the `directories` array. If it managed to find a match in any directory the function would return true.

```js
fileStructure = [{ "music": [{ "acoustic": ["vlad-gluschenko-stars-extended.mp3"] }, { "chinese": ["AlbumArtSmall.jpg", "Folder.jpg", "keys-of-moon-yugen.mp3"] }, { "lofi": ["le-gang-relax-man.mp3", "purple-cat-field-of-fireflies.mp3"] }] }, { "sounds": [{ "campfire": ["fire-crackle.mp3", "fire-rumble.mp3"] }, { "rain": ["rain-heavy.mp3", "rain-light.mp3", "rain-tapping.mp3"] }, { "thunderstorm": ["thunderstorm.mp3"] }, { "wind": ["wind-base.mp3", "wind-howling.mp3", "wind-rattling.mp3"] }] }]

function findFile(fileName, dir) {
    var directories = [];
    for (i in dir) {
        let entry = dir[i];

        // If entry is a dictionary, unpack into array
        if (entry.constructor == Object) {
            // If the file being searched for is itself a directory, then search the dictionary for a directory with the name of fileName
            if (Object.keys(entry).indexOf(fileName) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            entry = Object.values(entry);
        }

        // If entry is an array (meaning it is the inside of a directory)
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            directories.push(entry);
        }
        else if (entry == fileName) {
            console.log('Found the file:');
            console.log(entry);
            return entry;
        }

        // If item is the last item in directory and no files have matched, begin to search each of the sub-directories
        if (i == dir.length - 1) {
            for (directory of directories) {
                if (findFile(fileName, directory)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

fileExists = findFile('foo', fileStructure);
console.log('done', fileExists);

fileExists = findFile('lofi', fileStructure);
console.log('done', fileExists);
```